# What is the best way to display 3D text in Vtk

Tags: c++, vtk

I am working on vtk. I want to display Rich text in vtk. I have tried vtkTextActor3D this shows text in 3d on given location but when i rotate the graphics text is also get rotated. 
The text should follow the camera this is my requirement is their any better way to do this.

Even in have tried vtkVectorText and vtkFollower but vtkVectorText is not providing rich text.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the vtkTextActor.

```
txtActor->SetTextScaleModeToNone();
txtActor->SetDisplayPosition(100,100);
txtActor->SetInput("Text with fixed position");
```

if you really need 3D, then you can add your vtkTextActor3D to a new renderer instance and set the viewport to the desired position and turn off the interactive functionality.

e.g.

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> aRenderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
aRenderer->SetViewport(0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2); //specify size as necessary
aRenderer->AddViewProp(txtActor3d);
aRenderer->SetInteractive(0); //turn off interactor events
RenderWindow->AddRenderer(aRenderer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try [vtkCornerAnnotation](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCornerAnnotation.html)

Comment: this class shows text in corner of viewport i want to display text at given position. Like i want to display text at location 100, 100, 0 etc.

Comment: What about changing the orientation of the actor on a camera change so that the front follows the camera.